# (Cocos2dx-v3) Android - How to solve "cocos2d.h: No such file or directory"?

Tags: android, eclipse, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-android

In terminal at my cocos2dx project directory,
I typed

```
$ cocos run test -p android
```

and comes this error log.

```
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: MyGame_shared <= main.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: MyGame_shared <= AppDelegate.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: MyGame_shared <= HelloWorldScene.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: MyGame_shared <= CharacterSelectScene.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: MyGame_shared <= LanguageManager.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: MyGame_shared <= GameMaster.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: MyGame_shared <= Player.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] StaticLibrary  : libextension.a
In file included from jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:1:0:
jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.h:4:21: fatal error: cocos2d.h: No such file or directory
 #include "cocos2d.h"
                     ^
compilation terminated.
In file included from jni/hellocpp/main.cpp:1:0:
jni/../../Classes/AppDelegate.h:4:21: fatal error: cocos2d.h: No such file or directory
 #include "cocos2d.h"
                     ^
compilation terminated.
In file included from jni/../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp:1:0:
jni/../../Classes/AppDelegate.h:4:21: fatal error: cocos2d.h: No such file or directory
 #include "cocos2d.h"
                     ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/MyGame_shared/__/__/Classes/HelloWorldScene.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/MyGame_shared/__/__/Classes/AppDelegate.o] Error 1
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/MyGame_shared/hellocpp/main.o] Error 1
In file included from jni/../../Classes/Player.cpp:9:0:
jni/../../Classes/Player.h:12:21: fatal error: cocos2d.h: No such file or directory
 #include "cocos2d.h"
                     ^
compilation terminated.
In file included from jni/../../Classes/GameMaster.cpp:9:0:
jni/../../Classes/GameMaster.h:12:21: fatal error: cocos2d.h: No such file or directory
 #include "cocos2d.h"
                     ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/MyGame_shared/__/__/Classes/Player.o] Error 1
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/MyGame_shared/__/__/Classes/GameMaster.o] Error 1
In file included from jni/../../Classes/CharacterSelectScene.cpp:9:0:
jni/../../Classes/CharacterSelectScene.h:12:21: fatal error: cocos2d.h: No such file or directory
 #include "cocos2d.h"
                     ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/MyGame_shared/__/__/Classes/CharacterSelectScene.o] Error 1
In file included from jni/../../Classes/LanguageManager.cpp:2:0:
jni/../../Classes/LanguageManager.h:8:21: fatal error: cocos2d.h: No such file or directory
 #include "cocos2d.h"
                     ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs-debug/MyGame_shared/__/__/Classes/LanguageManager.o] Error 1
Error running command, return code: 2.
```

I found the similar problem in the link

[Cocos2d.h No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356181/cocos2d-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

But I didn't know how to

```
 "add the path to the folder that contains the cocos2d.h header file"
```

Can anyone tell me steps to solving this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably one of the very annoying errors that you get once you start your new life with `cocos2d-x`. There are a couple of things to get a check on.

> Import the libcocos2dx from eclipse

Press `Ctrl + N`

```
> Android Project from Existing Code 
    > yourDirectory\cocos2d-x-3.yourVersion\cocos2d\cocos\platform
```

Add if that does not help, you need to give absolute paths to your classes and `.cpp` files in `Android.mk` which I believe is what you need.

Expand your project list (I have assumed `test` is your project name)

```
   > test 
     > jni
       > Android.mk
```

Replace this:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/GameMaster.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/MyGame_shared.cpp \

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes
```

With this:

```
CPP_FILES := $(shell find $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes -name *.cpp)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(CPP_FILES:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(shell find $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes -type d)
```